# Jquery Cannot call method 'load' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery to load google maps after button toggle:

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.11&key=AIzaSyCK3XUMWOH0GIiuj3VeprakKZXoo_nDV08&sensor=true&' +
        'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Show map on category pages
        $(function () {
            $("#showonmap a").toggle(function () {
                $(this).children("#show_map").hide();
                $(this).children("#hide_map").show();
                //Reveal google maps multi
                //First create empty divs, if they exist don't create them
                if ($("#googlemap_multi").length == 0) {
                    $("#subheadergradient").before('<div class="googlemap_margin"></div><div id="googlemap_multi"></div><div class="googlemap_margin"></div>');
                }
                $(".googlemap_margin").fadeIn("slow", function () {
                    $("#googlemap_multi").animate({
                        height: 400
                    }, "slow", function () {
                        //load google maps
                        loadScript().load();
                    });
                });
            }, function () {
                $(this).children("#hide_map").hide();
                $(this).children("#show_map").show();
                //Hide google maps multi
                $("#googlemap_multi").animate({
                    height: 0
                }, "slow", function () {
                    $(".googlemap_margin").fadeOut("slow");
                });
            });
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

But this generates error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of undefined localhost:482
(anonymous function) localhost:482
d.complete jquery.min.js:4
f.fx.step jquery.min.js:4
h jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.tick
```

So toggle back function never gets executed.

This part:

```
//Hide google maps multi
$("#googlemap_multi").animate({height: 0},"slow", function(){
    $(".googlemap_margin").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

What is the problem?

ty.

Comment: Your `$("#googlemap_multi").animate()` callback is calling `loadScript().load()`. Unless `loadScript()` returns something with a `load()` method, you are going to be attempting to call `load()` on an `undefined` return type.

Comment: I think code is much easier to read when it is left aligned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you try to call `.load()` on a function that do not returns nothing?

Either just call `loadScript();`
or 
or make `loadScript` function return an object that has method `load`.

Comment: I got another error now: Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

The result of `loadScript()` doesn't have a method `load()`. All it does is load a script (async!).

Which `load()` are you trying to execute?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
loadScript().load();
```

But your method `loadScript` doesn't have any `return` statement, so basically you are calling the `load` method (chained) on `undefined`.

Comment: true that, but now I receive another error: Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object Object]